# List Directory with about 2,000,000 files using FTP Protocol

Tags: c#, linux, ftp, listdir

I have a directory with about 2,000,000 files on an FTP Server. This FTP Server is Linux-based. I want to list the files in this directory (file name with the last modification date), but neither Filezilla nor Core FTP Pro can do it and the list operation would fail. I have tried to write my own application in C# using FTPWebRequest class and run the ListDirectory method, but it fails to list the files in the directory too and the ftpwebrequest timed out.
Is there any way to list the name of So many files in a directory using any protocol (such as FTP, SMB, ...) or even by executing a bash script?

The Function to list directory in c# is:

```
public static List<string> ListFtpDirectory(string address, string userName, string password)
    {
        List<string> filesName = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(address);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                filesName =
                    reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return filesName;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add your existing code please in description

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: I have added the existing code...@Nicklaus Brain

Comment: Read again: *Questions **without a clear problem statement** are **not useful** to other readers*

Comment: does my question have such problem? I tried to write it clearly and have edited that @Sir Rufo

Comment: You write it fails. Well, how does it fail? Did you get an exception? If yes, what kind of exception and what error message?

Comment: While you don't provide a detailed error description *"...the ftpwebrequest timed out"* might indicate that the server is simply unable to create a listing containing this huge number of files within some reasonable time. It is not uncommon that listing such a huge directory can take some time, especially if one also wants to get things like modification time since the system needs to scan not only the directory but also visit the inode for each of the files. If you have access to the server I suggest to reorganize it into multiple directories with fewer files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fluent in C#, however you're not including the exact text of the error you're receiving.

The following is a Powershell script which should work in your environment:

```
$Server = "ftp://ftp.example.com/"
$User = "anonymous@example.com"
$Pass = "anonymous@anonymous.com"

Function Get-FtpDirectory($Directory) {

    # Credentials
    $FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$($Server)$($Directory)")
    $FTPRequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($User,$Pass)
    $FTPRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectoryDetails

    # Don't want Binary, Keep Alive unecessary.
    $FTPRequest.UseBinary = $False
    $FTPRequest.KeepAlive = $False

    $FTPResponse = $FTPRequest.GetResponse()
    $ResponseStream = $FTPResponse.GetResponseStream()

    # Create a nice Array of the detailed directory listing
    $StreamReader = New-Object System.IO.Streamreader $ResponseStream
    $DirListing = (($StreamReader.ReadToEnd()) -split [Environment]::NewLine)
    $StreamReader.Close()

    # Remove first two elements ( . and .. ) and last element (\n)
    # and take into account empty directories
    If ($DirListing.Length -gt 3) {
        $DirListing = $DirListing[2..($DirListing.Length-2)]
    }
    else {
        $DirListing = @{}    $DirListing = $DirListing[2..($DirListing.Length-2)] 
    }

    # Close the FTP connection so only one is open at a time
    $FTPResponse.Close()

    # This array will hold the final result
    $FileTree = @()

    # Loop through the listings
    foreach ($CurLine in $DirListing) {

        # Split line into space separated array
        $LineTok = ($CurLine -split '\ +')

        # Get the filename (can even contain spaces)
        $CurFile = $LineTok[8..($LineTok.Length-1)]

        # Figure out if it's a directory. Super hax.
        $DirBool = $LineTok[0].StartsWith("d")

        # Determine what to do next (file or dir?)
        If ($DirBool) {
            # Recursively traverse sub-directories
            $FileTree += ,(Get-FtpDirectory "$($Directory)$($CurFile)/")
        } Else {
            # Add the output to the file tree
            $FileTree += ,"$($Directory)$($CurFile)"
        }
    }

    Return $FileTree

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Walkabout Tigger, but this is not working as well and it fails to retrieve directory information.